# input/button issue in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

For some reason my searchbox is not appearing correctly in ie. The search box is not visible at all and the button is in the corner where it shouldn't be.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="?" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Modern Spaces" />
    <button type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
</div><!--searchBoxOne-->
```

And the CSS:

```
.searchbox input {
color: #b0b0b0;
width: 430px;
height: 28px;
margin-top: 32px;
padding: 10px 5px;
float: left;    
font-size: 20px;
border: 0;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; 
box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #7b7a7a;     
}

.searchbox button{
overflow: visible;
position: relative;
margin: 39px 0 0 -40px;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 36px;
background:url(../images/srch_button.png) no-repeat;

}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What version of IE?  Minus the placeholder (which doesn't work in any version of IE yet), it looks fine in IE9.  http://jsfiddle.net/SJLkK/

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="?" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Modern Spaces" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
</div><!--searchBoxOne-->
```

Or the old way instead of `<button type="submit" value="submit" />` insert this

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
```

Comment: yeah ie can be disagreeable with incorrect html.  Button tags text content work like textareas.

Comment: I did it the old way as user1430562 suggested and it works in ie now. But now the placeholder doesn't disappear as i click on the search field (in all the browsers). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Then he could set a name option for the input like this
`<input type="text" name="searchstring" placeholder="Search Modern Spaces" />`
Maybe that is the problem why it is not working right

Comment: @TulkinTg: IE doesn't support placeholders.

Comment: @TulkinTg That is the placeholders role when you click in the input box then the text of placeholder is disappearing and if you click somewhere else then it must be there again!

Comment: @Rocket: Would this be the right way?  <input name="search" type="text" value="Search Modern Spaces" />

Comment: @TulkinTg: To do what?  The only way to get "placeholders" in IE is to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Rocket: To "imitate" placeholder without using the keyword. But I got you. I'll ask google how to do it with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

[`box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) is only supported on IE9+.  If you are using IE < 9, `box-shadow` is ignored, so the textbox isn't visible because it has a border of 0.